# install polemarch software (web GUI for ansible playbooks) in rhel 7.7

Tags: linux, python, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ansible

I tried to install `polemarch` software (web GUI for ansible playbooks) in RHEL 7.7 VM created from virtual software

- I followed the instruction in the [`polemarch` documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/polemarch/stable/polemarch.pdf)
- I subscribed to RedHat Enterprise and installed prerequisites software packages `yum`, `pip`, `python`, `virtualenv` and other repositories.
- I tried with the commands given below

```
    virtualenv --python=python3.6 /opt/polemarch
    sudo chown -R polemarch:polemarch /opt/polemarch
    sudo -u polemarch -i
    source /opt/polemarch/bin/activate
    pip install -U polemarch[mysql]
```

- But I am struck with the installation of `polemarch` using `PyPI` raising the following error:

```
Failing to build wheel for python-ldap and mysqlclient
```

- Also, I wasn't able to edit the configuration files to get started with `polemarch` service.
- I researched and tried with the solutions for the dependencies error, but still facing the same issue

Can you kindly provide your help to resolve the issue with your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to install devel packages to install some python packages with pip.
First, make sure you have installed the development tools:

```
yum install gcc-c++ python-devel
```

Next, for mysqlclient you need the devel package of your mysql distribution:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

And for python-ldap you need the devel package of openldap:

```
yum install openldap-devel
```